# laravel return download creates extra file

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using following codes to create zip file in Laravel:

```
$files = Answer::where('questionid', $questionId)
                ->pluck('answer')
                ->all();

$zip = new ZipArchive;

$zip_name = time() . "_$questionId" . ".zip";

if ($zip->open(storage_path($zip_name), ZipArchive::CREATE) === true) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $relativeNameInZipFile = explode('/', $file)[3];
        $zip->addFile(Storage::path($file), $relativeNameInZipFile);
    }
    $zip->close();
}

return Storage::download($zip_name);
```

It works properly.But when the last line of the code that returns file to download create an extra zip file in the storage!

```
return Storage::download($zip_name);
```

Why!!??

Comment: So you have both the original file created here: `if ($zip->open(storage_path($zip_name), ZipArchive::CREATE) === true) {` and another one created due to `return Storage::download($zip_name);`? can you confirm this behavior? i.e. delete all files in the specific storage directory and determine if it wasn't just an old file that was created by running this before. side note: if you don't need the file kept on the server you can actually use `ZipStream` https://github.com/maennchen/ZipStream-PHP

Comment: It was asked by Alex, not me.

Comment: I have found why it is happening. Because I'm downloading the zip file with IDM(Internet download manager) it create an other file in the server! @Alex